# Get data from nested array of objects which are not present in another nested array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have the following arrs:

```
data:[
  {
      "servicename": "Income Tax Return Filling",
      "serviceid": 10,
      "clients": [
        {
          "serviceid": 10,
          "periodicity": "H",
          "clientnos": [
            "A2222"
          ]
        },
        {
          "serviceid": 10,
          "periodicity": "M",
          "clientnos": [
            "B0002",
            "B3064",
            "CI0155"
          ]
        },
        {
          "serviceid": 10,
          "periodicity": "Q",
          "clientnos": [
            "C0166"
          ]
        },
        {
          "serviceid": 10,
          "periodicity": "Y",
          "clientnos": [
            "C0023",
            "C001"
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "servicename": "GSTR 3B",
      "serviceid": 17,
      "clients": [
        {
          "serviceid": 17,
          "periodicity": "M",
          "clientnos": [
            "C0008",
            "C0004",
            "C0023",
            "C001"
          ]
        },
        {
          "serviceid": 17,
          "periodicity": "Y",
          "clientnos": [
            "C0001",
            "C0005",
            "C0190"
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
]
and
"result": [
    [
      {
        "clientnos": [
          "B0002",
          "B3064",
          "CI0155"
        ],
        "compperiod": "Mar",
        "serviceid": 10
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        "clientnos": [
          "C0004"
        ],
        "compperiod": "Mar",
        "serviceid": 17
      },
      {
        "clientnos": [
          "C0023",
          "C0004",
          "C001"
        ],
        "compperiod": "May",
        "serviceid": 17
      }
    ],
]
```

and a `monthArr = ['Feb','Mar','Apr','May']` and value of periodicity as `priodicity= 'M'`. And each month in the monthArr is referred as compperiod.
I want the following output.

```
output:[
   [
      {
        "clientnos": [],
        "compperiod": "Mar",
        "serviceid": 10
      },
      {
        "clientnos": [
          "B0002",
          "B3064",
          "CI0155"
        ],
        "compperiod": "Feb",
        "serviceid": 10
      },
      {
        "clientnos": [
          "B0002",
          "B3064",
          "CI0155"
        ],
        "compperiod": "Apr",
        "serviceid": 10
      },
      {
        "clientnos": [
          "B0002",
          "B3064",
          "CI0155"
        ],
        "compperiod": "May",
        "serviceid": 10
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        "clientnos": [
          "C0008",
          "C0023",
          "C001"
        ],
        "compperiod": "Mar",
        "serviceid": 17
      },
      {
        "clientnos": [
          "C0008"
        ],
        "compperiod": "May",
        "serviceid": 17
      },
      {
        "clientnos": [
          "C0008",
          "C0004",
          "C0023",
          "C001"
        ],
        "compperiod": "Feb",
        "serviceid": 17
      },
      {
        "clientnos": [
          "C0008",
          "C0004",
          "C0023",
          "C001"
        ],
        "compperiod": "Apr",
        "serviceid": 17
      }
    ],
]
```

So what's happening in the above data is for each month in the `monthArr`, I want to show those clientnos in the output which are not present in the result arr. 
For ex:
In data arr for service name: 'Income Tax return filling' the clients array consists of clientnos based on different peridocity i.e 'H','M','Y'. I have set the `periodicity = 'M'`. So now I have to get the clientnos from clients array where `perodicity = 'M'` for each service in the data array where a clients array object with `periodicity='M'` exists.
After that in the results arr the sub array gets generate after an sql query. Here I have directly posted the data from the query.
Now I want the following operations to take place to get the output.
The output array consists of data based on the result arr.
For ex: Let's take

```
result[2] = [
      {
        "clientnos": [
          "C0004"
        ],
        "compperiod": "Mar",
        "serviceid": 17
      },
      {
        "clientnos": [
          "C0023",
          "C0004",
          "C001"
        ],
        "compperiod": "May",
        "serviceid": 17
      }
]
```

So now in the output data for service id 17 I want to get those clientnos which are not present for each month in the monthArr
i.e In the data arr for serviceid 17 and periodicity 'M' we have the following `clientnos = ["C0008", "C0004", "C0023", "C001"]`. Now in the result[2] for serviceid `17` and month `Mar` we have only `"C0004"` in the clientnos arr, so in the output it should show `["C0008", "C0023", "C001"]` in the clientnos arr for serviceid 17 and month `Mar`.
Now for the month of `Feb`, there is no data in result[2]. So now we have to show clientnos `["C0008", "C0004", "C0023", "C001"]` i.e all clientnos for the month of feb in the output. Same we have to do it with muliple services in the data arr and for each month in the monthArr.

I have tried the following way.

```
var result = []
    for (const element of listService) {
      for (const period of element.clients) {
        if (periodicity == period.periodicity) {
          //Sql query to get sub array present in the result arr.
     // i.e if I execute this query for service id 17 I get result[2]

          periodArr.forEach(p => {
            const r = _.filter(data, { compperiod: p });
            if (r[0]) {
              const index = data.findIndex(obj => obj.compperiod == r[0].compperiod);
              data[index] = {
                "clientnos": period.clientnos.filter(e => !r[0].clientnos.includes(e)),
                "compperiod": p,
                "serviceid": element.serviceid
              }
            } else {
              data.push({
                "clientnos": period.clientnos,
                "compperiod": p,
                "serviceid": element.serviceid
              })
            }
          });
          result.push(data);
        }
      }
    };
```

I have achieved the output in the above way. But is there a way where I can achieve this in an more optimized way. If yes, then how?